# Some website content causes BeautifulSoup (and lxml) to restart Python session

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm fetching and parsing a medium-large quantity of webpages.  I noticed my script was spontaneously ending with a Python session restart.  Thus far it only seems to happen when I try to make soup out of the nasa.gov page. i.e.:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nasa.gov')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page)

=====================================RESTART=======================================
```

Does anyone know why this might be occurring and whether there's anyway I can avoid it?  It doesn't throw an exception or anything, the session just restarts.  This happens on two different machines, although I'd be interested if it isn't reproducible by others (I'm using Python 2.7.2 - Enthought Distribution)

EDIT/UPDATE:

I've just tried to substitute lxml for BeautifulSoup, but it causes the same spontaneous restart. i.e.

```
from lxml import html
page=html.parse('http://www.nasa.gov')

============================== RESTART =================================
```

As soon as Python opens and tries to parse the page the session restarts.  Interestingly, reading the page and printing it to the console works fine.

Comment: I think you need to run .read() on the socket first, extract the string then run BeautifulSoup on the string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately adding .read() doesn't help. The code above works perfectly for hundreds of other sites I've used it on.  This one site for some reason causes the session to restart.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I am seeing same thing on Windows machine, but on VPS with Linux (Debian) same code with same input works fine without hickups.
Now all hail Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Doctype is wrong for that url. Try this:

```
page=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nasa.gov/').read().replace("<!DOCTYPE \"xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'\">", "<!DOCTYPE html>")

soup=BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: My bad.  That 'html' in the second edit is a typo.  I of course used http.  I'd really like someone else to try this to see if they can replicate the issue.

Comment: I tried both on 2.7.4(windows). Lxml was fine and bs4 crashed.

Comment: I see the problem, it's a mangled doctype. I'm updating my answer.